# RestSharp error in Azure Pipeline: 'RestResponseBase.StatusCode' is not supported by the language

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, restsharp

After upgrading to v107 I'm getting this error on the Azure Pipeline:

##[error]XXXXXXXXXXX.Shared.Integration\APIClients\XXXXXXXXXXRESTClientBase.cs(114,43): Error CS1545: Property, indexer, or event 'RestResponseBase.StatusCode' is not supported by the language; try directly calling accessor methods 'RestResponseBase.get_StatusCode()' or 'RestResponseBase.set_StatusCode(??)'

The code compiles on my laptop, but for some reason it fails on the pipeline.

Could it be related to this message in the upgrade guide?
*"The most important change is that RestSharp stop using the legacy HttpWebRequest class, and uses well-known 'HttpClient' instead. This move solves lots of issues, like hanging connections due to improper HttpClient instance cache, updated protocols support, and many other problems."*

I'm using .NET core 3.1 which still has LTS.

An example of where compilation fails is in this example:

```
    private bool RequestFailed(HttpStatusCode statusCode)
    {
        var result = statusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError ||
                     statusCode == HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable ||
                     statusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        if (result) Logger.Verbose("API Call resulted in status code: " + statusCode.ToString());

        return result;
    }

    private bool HandleResult(RestResponse response)
    {
        return RequestFailed(response.StatusCode);
    }
```

Which errors on the line:

```
return RequestFailed(response.StatusCode);
```

Similar issue:

error CS1545: Property, indexer, or event 'Parameter.Name' is not supported by the language

```
        public static void SetCorrelationId(RestRequest request, Guid? correlationId)
        {
            var existingHeader = request.Parameters.Where(x => x.Name == CorrelationIdHeaderKey).FirstOrDefault();
            ...
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

The issue is caused by .NET Core 3.1 SDK being unable to work with properties that have `init` instead of `set`, although RestSharp is built to target .NET Standard, and should work with .NET Core 3.1.

It works on your machine because you have a newer SDK (.NET 5 or 6). Newer SDKs can build for legacy targets, so it works just fine. In your CI pipeline you, most probably, use the .NET Core 3.1 SDK to build the solution, and it fails.

Comment: MY scenario was exactly as explained - locally my SDK was new enough, but pipeline the SDK was very low. Going to definition for RestResponseBase.Content revealed a getter and init using RestSharp v107, so I downgraded to v106 and the getter/init became a getter/setter and hey presto my pipeline build now works fine. Thanks both.

Comment: We are goi going to replace `init` with `set` in the next version to mitigate this issue.

Comment: Has anyone gotten this to work?  I am encountering the same issue using Jenkins, and have installed the .Net 5, .Net 6, and .Net Core SDKs to no avail.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev this still has not been fixed. Can you all please release a minor update or something to fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there was a fix for that introduced a few days ago: *"change RestBaseResponse property bag to setters from init"*

https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/releases/tag/108.0.0